# Android to CS cart API integration

Tags: android, json, cs-cart

I am creating an e-commerce android application. I have done with front end now i want to integrate api to android for backend. Website is developed using CS Cart. Now I have to integrate that CS Cart api and I do not know how to integrate this type of api i.e. how to encode and fetch json data from that. 
Can someone please help me in this?

I also went through this link http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.1.x/api/index.html but did not find any useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cs-cart API in this 3 simple steps:

1. First of all, you need create an admin type account, and **enable api access** for that account. When you enable, Cs-cart show you an **API Key** for that account.
2. **Follow Cs-cart API docs** and make Http request to any **entity** you want following this format (Example for make request to *Products* entity):

(GET Method) `https://username:APIKey@yourdomain.com/api/products`

3. It will return a list of products in JSON format. You can parse it in your Android App.

You should use https request to protect your request data.